# Conversion of C++ statement into Java

Tags: java, c++

Probably my head is not working but how can i convert this into Java

```
int c = 0;

// Code

c = !c;
return c;
```

Comment: `c = !c` -> `c = c == 0 ? 1 : 0`

Comment: @MuhammadUmar you are trying to change the `c` value or you are trying to return the Boolean value, by checking whether `c` is not equal to `c` ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you're going to return int then `return c == 0 ? 1 : 0;`

Answer (score 3):

you probably want to use **boolean** instead.

```
public boolean method() {
  boolean bool = false;    
  return !bool;
}
```

Comment: +1. The C code is using the int as a boolean, so use the boolean type in Java.

Comment: @lpinto.eu: Indeed, but the question is about how to translate to Java, not to better C++.

Comment: when translating to Java, better C++ is an intermediate step.